# Jenkins - transforming sql query result into string with ";" as delimiter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, string-aggregation

I have a Jenkins batch command step, which makes query to MSSQL DB and return a result:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn"

SQLQUERY="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.exe" -S "test-sqlsrv.database.windows.net" -U "someuser" -P "somepass" -d "somedb" -W -Q "SELECT tt.Name FROM Transport.Topic tt, Transport.Root tr, Transport.DDS dds WHERE tr.Id = tt.TransportId AND dds.TransportId = tr.Id AND dds.QOSProfile = 'Asset_Profile' group by tt.Name order by tt.Name">test.txt
```

Result in test.txt:

```
Name
----
value1
DigitalIO
value2
J1939
SKF15
value3
VIMS

(7 rows affected)
```

Is there any way, either by transform test.txt result, or by remaking sql query on previous step, to receive following output in file or variable:

```
    value1;DigitalIO;value2;J1939;SKF15;value3;VIMS
```

Comment: try this query `with t as (
  select 'value1' as Name union all
  select 'DigitalIO' union all
  select 'value2' union all
  select 'J1939' union all
  select 'SKF15' union all
  select 'value3' union all
  select 'VIMS'
  )
select distinct
  stuff((
    select ',' + Name
    from t
    for xml path ('')
  ),1,1,'')
from t`

Comment: @JaimeDrq sorry, I'm newbie in sql queries - can you clarify - I need to run this as a part of query mentioned in me question? Or as a second query? because it gives me a syntax error.

Comment: Try to run this query isolated, not inside a batch of queries, because the with clause must be always preempted with a semi-colon. I cannot ask this question because it has been already marked as duplicated.

Comment: You can try it works from here: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/862683/50857777

Comment: Ok, this query gives me my expected result, as I wanted, but how this implement? Because outputs are different on different db's?

Comment: This is sql server sintax, and you marked that technology in your description

Comment: Oh, thanks for link you provided. I will try to assemble work solution.

Comment: ok good luck! :)

Comment: Thanks, I was able to assemble right query, using your approach! You can copy it as an answer, so I can mark it as a right comment.

Comment: No problem don't worry, I can't because it has been marked as duplicated. Happy to know it works

Comment: @JaimeDrq Anyway, thanks one more time :)